# How to duplicating perspective zoom home screen feature in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, uiimageview

As we all know, iOS 8 having a perspective zoom feature in the home screen which zooms depend on the angle of a device and how it moves.

I want to duplicate that feature inside my app. I found a question to find out the angle of a device here.

[How can I determine the angle of the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690743/how-can-i-determine-the-angle-of-the-device)

[Measuring tilt angle with CMMotionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646433/measuring-tilt-angle-with-cmmotionmanager)

I need to discuss the ideas to zoom the image depend on the angle of a device. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** It is a duplicate of this question: [iOS 7 parallax effect in my view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972994/ios-7-parallax-effect-in-my-view-controller)

Thanks for you help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 parallax effect in my view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972994/ios-7-parallax-effect-in-my-view-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is called a 'parallax effect' and there is built-in support in Cocoa Touch for it. You don't need to re-invent the wheel to add that effect to your apps. Search the web for information on `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect), in particular, is Apple's brief documentation on it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. I asked to close my own question as a duplicate of other question. Thanks again.